# PHP array creation with information displayed in a dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have an array with information that is basically just a list of integers and then coinciding with these integers are a specific calculated value for each integer. The size of this array will depend on the inputted value, but won't be more than 10 entries.

I want to make a dropdown menu that the user can choose one of these integers and then the coinciding calculation will be shown to the user. I also need a specific value (that depends on the calculation) to be selected by default, as a sort of "best" answer.

One possible thing that I would need to display:

Options in dropdown:
1
2
3

Coinciding options for display
23.536
36.577
40.164

With the auto selected value being the second entry (will depend on the calculation). Arrays may be anywhere from 1-10 entries.

Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide some sample input, calculations, and output?

Comment: I don't know how to go about displaying arrays as dropdown + displayed information. I assume it's going to be something like     <SELECT Name="dropdown">
  <OPTION selected Value = "<?php $_POST['array[best]'] ?>"> <?php $_POST['array[0]' ?>
  <OPTION Value = "1"> <?php $_POST[1] ?>
  </select>
but somehow have an iterative process to decide how many Select values there can be. I've edited opening post to show possible data array.

Answer (score 0):

With no initial code given by the question asker : iterate through the array via a for or while loop - building the list item (`li`) for each entry. then you'll need to either tie in some JS if you wish to process the calculation client side Or construct a mechanism that accepts the value via a request to the server and responds in kind. Good luck have fun!

Comment: Do you have a source or example on how to do this? I can create the array with calculated values but I don't know how to program in a dropdown with size varying on the size of my array and tell it which value should be auto-selected.

Comment: Sort of the meat isn't it? If you have code you are struggling with Id be happy to suggest improvements / corrections - but you need to attempt to swim before someone will throw a life donut

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying here. Yes, the meat of my problem is that I don't know how to go about displaying my array as stated. I don't have code on how to do this because I am unaware of any method that will make it work properly, thus the question.

Comment: These might be helpful sites : php.net , http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning.en.html , http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

good luck